# XML Values to retrieve in single Column with Any(,) Delimiter

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

My Xml file

```
<Detials xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Tests>
  <Test Name="Test1" TotalMarks="100">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test2" TotalMarks="200">65</Test>
  <Test Name="Test3" TotalMarks="150">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test4" TotalMarks="150"></Test>
    </Tests>
</Detials>
```

I want to query it back to view as

```
TestName         |TotalMarks     |ScoreObtained** 
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4|100,200,150,150| 95,65,95,|
```

I tried with this ,But not able to get the Result above as i want,I got the error as ***XQuery [T1.XMLData.query()]: ")" was expected.***

```
Select 

                           TestName  = x.c.query ('STUFF((SELECT 
              '','' + fd.v.value(''(.)[1]'', ''varchar(100)'')
           FROM 
              XMLwithOpenXML
           CROSS APPLY
              XMLData.nodes(''/Tests/Test/@Name'') AS fd(v)
           FOR XML PATH('''')
          ), 1, 1, ''''') 


                        From T1 s
                        Cross Apply s.XMLData.nodes('/Detials') AS x(c)
```

Help me to solve this !

Thanks,Jayendran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT STUFF(@x.query('for $a in (*:Detials/Tests/Test/@Name) return <a>{concat(",", $a)}</a>').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS ListOfName
SELECT STUFF(@x.query('for $a in (*:Detials/Tests/Test/@TotalMarks) return <a>{concat(",", $a)}</a>').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS ListOfTotalMarks
SELECT STUFF(@x.query('for $a in (*:Detials/Tests/Test) return <a>{concat(",", $a)}</a>').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS ListOfInnerHTML
```

**[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=69e34292f006af762b484bac5b3a598a)**

Note: first `SELECT` could be formatted like this:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    @x.query('for $a in (*:Detials/Tests/Test/@Name) 
        return <a>{concat(",", $a)}</a>')
    .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 
    1, 1, '') AS ListOfName
```

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan Solved my big problem :)

Comment: I like this approach, +1 from my side. Just one hint: You can reduce your `XQuery` to `for $a in (*:Detials/Tests/Test/@Name) return concat(",", $a)`. Another even shorter approach might be `data()`, as long as `@Name` has not got any blanks: `REPLACE(@x.query(N'data(/Detials/Tests/Test/@Name)').value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),' ',',')`

Comment: The result of `query()` method should be (from my point of view) a valid XML data. Instead, proposed solution will generate a plain string stored by SQL Server as XML.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, yeah, sure, I did not mean to remove the `.value(...)`... There's just no need to create an element `<a>` and use a sub-query within `{...}`.

Comment: @Shnugo: I want clear code. I have to repeat my self, query() method returns an XML, so the return statement from XQuery should return also an XML. The name of element (<a> or <b> ... ) doesn't matter. Even query() method will return something like `,bla,bla,bleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah` this will be an XML and it needs a value() or CONVERT to [N]VARCHAR(n). It's a two steps process: query + value/CONVERT.

Comment: @Shnugo: That code `REPLACE( ... something with spaces .... many many spaces ... or something with just one space ..., 'space(1) ?', ',')` will not return proper results when source string of R function contains space(s).

Comment: Well, that's why I wrote * has not got any blanks*... I'd appreciate a `data()` function with a delimiter parameter. No idea, why this is a blank a just a blank... Happy Coding

Comment: @BogdanSahlean When i tried with some changes in the xml i'm unable to get the result.Could you kindly look it,and please help me to solve it.
Here what i tried https://gist.github.com/jayendranarumugam/15be48c1c24e844f637645a27def0ed5

Comment: @JayendranRosh: It's simple but add this new info to your question or [better] create a new question. Before string concatenation with query() and value() we have to shred original XML into separate rows - one row for ever <Tests> element.  This is a Q & A site.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Could you please help me with this,I Created a new question which can be helpful for others too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452487/xml-values-to-retrieve-in-single-column-with-any-delimiter-2

Comment: @JayendranRosh: I'm going to try.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Thanks for you Effort !

Answer (score 1):

> 'TestName  = x.c.query ('STUFF((SELECT ...'

You tried to put a 'T-SQL'-statement **within** an `XQuery`-expression... That cannot work...

### This approach seems dangerous...

With the given example the last entry is doubled. Your expected output shows three values as `TestName`, but four values as `TotalMarks`and four values (with an empty value at the end) as `ScoreObtained`. Your approach seems to me very dangerous... What, if there are two "Test1" entries? You would not know, whether the `TotalMarks="200"` belongs to this, or to "Test2". Is this really the output you need?

### A possible solution

You might try this, but I really doubt, that your approach is correct:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Detials xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Tests>
  <Test Name="Test1" TotalMarks="100">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test2" TotalMarks="200">65</Test>
  <Test Name="Test3" TotalMarks="150">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test3" TotalMarks="150"></Test>
    </Tests>
</Detials>';

WITH DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT t.value(N'@Name','nvarchar(max)') AS Name
          ,t.value(N'@TotalMarks','nvarchar(max)') AS Mark
          ,t.value(N'.','nvarchar(max)') AS Point --use 'text()[1]' to avoid empty values
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/Detials/Tests/Test') AS A(t)
)
SELECT
    (
        STUFF(
        (
        SELECT ', ' + Name FROM DerivedTable GROUP BY Name ORDER BY Name FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')
    ) AS TestName
   ,(
        STUFF(
        (
        SELECT ', ' + Mark FROM DerivedTable ORDER BY Name FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')
    ) AS TotalMarks
   ,(
        STUFF(
        (
        SELECT ', ' + Point FROM DerivedTable ORDER BY Name FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')
    ) AS ScoreObtained;
```

The result

```
TestName            TotalMarks          ScoreObtained
Test1, Test2, Test3 100, 200, 150, 150  95, 65, 95,
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the Test 4 in my TestName Column.I updated my Question here.Please see the updated one

Comment: @JayendranRosh, Okay, but I would not reccomend this output format... However, my answer will work with your corrected data too... Just remove the `GROUP BY Name` (although it does not hurt...)

Comment: Yes @Shnugo its working Fine.+1 for your Answer and your quick response.I will go with the above Approach,also considering the your comment in above :)