# XML Values to retrieve in single Column with Any(,) Delimiter (2)

Tags: sql-server, xml

```
declare @x xml =
'<Detials xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Tests>
  <Test Name="Test1" TotalMarks="100">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test2" TotalMarks="200">65</Test>
  <Test Name="Test3" TotalMarks="150">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test4" TotalMarks="150"></Test>
   </Tests>
   <Tests>
  <Test Name="Test1" TotalMarks="100">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test2" TotalMarks="200">65</Test>
  <Test Name="Test3" TotalMarks="150">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test4" TotalMarks="150"></Test>
    </Tests>
</Detials>'
```

When i queried like this

```
SELECT STUFF(
    @x.query('for $a in (*:Detials/Tests/Test/@Name) 
        return <a>{concat(",", $a)}</a>')
    .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 
    1, 1, '') AS ListOfName
```

I get like this

**ListofName**
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4

But Want to shred the xml based on the <**Test**> Which can give the result like this below

**ListofName**

Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4

Please help me here to shred original XML into separate rows before  string concatenation with query() and value()

Thanks in Advance ,Jayendran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
declare @x xml =
'<Detials xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Tests>
  <Test Name="Test1" TotalMarks="100">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test2" TotalMarks="200">65</Test>
  <Test Name="Test3" TotalMarks="150">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test4" TotalMarks="150"></Test>
   </Tests>
   <Tests>
  <Test Name="Test1" TotalMarks="100">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test2" TotalMarks="200">65</Test>
  <Test Name="Test3" TotalMarks="150">95</Test>
  <Test Name="Test4" TotalMarks="150"></Test>
    </Tests>
</Detials>'

-- Edit 1
SELECT  XmlTable.OriginalID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.XmlCol) AS RowNum, y.ListOfName
FROM (SELECT 1 AS OriginalID, @x AS XmlCol) AS XmlTable -- Edit 2
CROSS APPLY XMLTable.XmlCol.nodes('*:Detials/Tests') AS x(XmlCol)
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT STUFF(x.XmlCol.query('for $a in (Test/@Name) return <a>{concat(",", $a)}</a>').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
) AS y(ListOfName)
-- End of Edit 1
```

**[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=da002b4718e30677e04993a18078657d)**

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan Sahlean !. Given the Example is Perfect ,if we store the whole xml in to a @x variable.If i store it in a column in a table.Lets say my table is XMLTAble and Column which having the xml file will be Xmlcol. How will the query changes accordingly ?

Comment: @JayendranRosh: See Edit 1.

Comment: It gives error. i'm seeing a Scalar Variable @x in (SELECT 1,@x) why is that so ?

This is the error i got 

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@x".
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: @JayendranRosh: There is nothing wrong with above source code. You could check by analysing online demo. Make sure you have copy-paste all source code, including DECLARE statement.

Comment: Your code works perfect.But what i asked is without declaring a scalar variable **@x**.How could this be done ? To be very Clear, my Entire XML file is Stored under under a column(XMLCol) in a table (XMLTable).(In that case we doesn't need a **@x** scalar variable to store the Entire Xml file).So during the queries we can use the table name and column name itself (without a **@x**-scalar Variable)

Comment: @JayendranRosh: You could replace that (SELECT ...) with a table (XmlTable) or table variable (@XmlTable AS XmlTable) having minimum two columns: OriginalID and XmlCol (XML).

Comment: @JayendranRosh: See Edit 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146276/discussion-between-jayendran-rosh-and-bogdan-sahlean).